# Rotating a cube in modern opengl... looks strange

Tags: scala, opengl, 3d, lwjgl, opengl-3

I'm somewhat lost, really lost.

I'm trying to rotate a cube (just around the y-axis for now) and this is the (ugly and wrong) outcome:

[image]

This is the code to rotate the matrix:

```
def rotate(axis: Vector3, angle: Float): Unit =
{
    val cosAngle: Float = Math.cos(angle).toFloat
    val sinAngle: Float = Math.sin(angle).toFloat

    val oneMinusCosAngle: Float = 1.0f - cosAngle

    val xy: Float = axis.x * axis.y
    val xz: Float = axis.x * axis.z

    val yz: Float = axis.y * axis.z

    val xs: Float = axis.x * sinAngle
    val ys: Float = axis.y * sinAngle
    val zs: Float = axis.z * sinAngle

    val f00: Float = axis.x * axis.x * oneMinusCosAngle + cosAngle
    val f01: Float = xy * oneMinusCosAngle + zs
    val f02: Float = xz * oneMinusCosAngle - ys

    val f10: Float = xy * oneMinusCosAngle - zs
    val f11: Float = axis.y * axis.y * oneMinusCosAngle + cosAngle
    val f12: Float = yz * oneMinusCosAngle + xs

    val f20: Float = xz * oneMinusCosAngle + ys
    val f21: Float = yz * oneMinusCosAngle - xs
    val f22: Float = axis.z * axis.z * oneMinusCosAngle + cosAngle

    val t00: Float = this.m00 * f00 + this.m10 * f01 + this.m20 * f02
    val t01: Float = this.m01 * f00 + this.m11 * f01 + this.m21 * f02
    val t02: Float = this.m02 * f00 + this.m12 * f01 + this.m22 * f02
    val t03: Float = this.m03 * f00 + this.m13 * f01 + this.m23 * f02
    val t10: Float = this.m00 * f10 + this.m10 * f11 + this.m20 * f12
    val t11: Float = this.m01 * f10 + this.m11 * f11 + this.m21 * f12
    val t12: Float = this.m02 * f10 + this.m12 * f11 + this.m22 * f12
    val t13: Float = this.m03 * f10 + this.m13 * f11 + this.m23 * f12

    this.m00 = t00
    this.m01 = t01
    this.m02 = t02
    this.m03 = t03

    this.m10 = t10
    this.m11 = t11
    this.m12 = t12
    this.m13 = t13

    this.m20 = this.m00 * f20 + this.m10 * f21 + this.m20 * f22
    this.m21 = this.m01 * f20 + this.m11 * f21 + this.m21 * f22
    this.m22 = this.m02 * f20 + this.m12 * f21 + this.m22 * f22
    this.m23 = this.m03 * f20 + this.m13 * f21 + this.m23 * f22
}
```

It's heavily inspired by: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.java which is no longer a part of lwjgl 3

the cube itself is made up out of these vertices, indices and texture coordinates

```
val vertices: Array[Float] = Array(
    -0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,

    -0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f,
    0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,

    0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f,
    0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,

    -0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f,
    -0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,

    -0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,
    -0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,

    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,-0.5f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f
  )

  val indices: Array[Int] = Array(
    0,1,3,
    3,1,2,
    4,5,7,
    7,5,6,
    8,9,11,
    11,9,10,
    12,13,15,
    15,13,14,
    16,17,19,
    19,17,18,
    20,21,23,
    23,21,22
  )

  val textureCoords: Array[Float] = Array(
    0,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,0,

    0,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,0,

    0,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,0,

    0,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,0,

    0,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,0,

    0,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,0
  )
```

Its model-matrix is calculated like this:

```
def calculateModelMatrix(position: Vector3, rotation: Vector3, scale: Float): Matrix4 =
{
    val matrix: Matrix4 = Matrix4.Identity
    matrix.translate(position)
    matrix.rotate(new Vector3(1,0,0), Math.toRadians(rotation.x).toFloat)
    matrix.rotate(new Vector3(0,1,0), Math.toRadians(rotation.y).toFloat)
    matrix.rotate(new Vector3(0,0,1), Math.toRadians(rotation.z).toFloat)
    matrix.scale(new Vector3(scale, scale, scale))

    matrix
}
```

Rendering the cube from the front works like a charm. I've not yet implemented moving the "camera", so maybe the viewMatrix is wrong?

ViewMatrix is calculated each frame (in the camera), like this:

```
def calculateViewMatrix(): Matrix4 =
{
    val matrix: Matrix4 = Matrix4.Identity
    matrix.rotate(new Vector3(1,0,0), Math.toRadians(this.pitch).toFloat)
    matrix.rotate(new Vector3(0,1,0), Math.toRadians(this.yaw).toFloat)
    matrix.translate(new Vector3(-this.position.x, -this.position.y, -this.position.z))
    matrix
}
```

If you need additional code, I can provide everything, I just didn't want to post all the code and discourage a lot of people.

**edit**:

Adding shader code and projectionMatrix generation as per comments:

```
def calculateProjectionMatrix(): Matrix4 =
{
    val aspectRatio: Float = 1024 / 768 // TODO get this from somewhere
    val yScale: Float = ((1.0f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio).toFloat
    val xScale: Float = yScale / aspectRatio
    val frustumLength = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE

    val matrix: Matrix4 = Matrix4.Zero
    matrix.m00 = xScale
    matrix.m11 = yScale
    matrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustumLength)
    matrix.m23 = -1.0f
    matrix.m32 = -((2.0f * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustumLength)

    matrix
}
```

(Yes, window measurements match 1024*768)

projectionMatrix gets set once as it never changes.

Shader-Code:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 passTextureCoords;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    passTextureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

and, modelViewProjectionMatrix is calculated (and set) each frame, like this:

```
modelViewProjectionMatrix = Matrix4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, modelMatrix)
```

where viewProjetionMatrix is:

```
def calculateViewProjectionMatrix(): Matrix4 =
{
    Matrix4.multiply(this.projectionMatrix, this.viewMatrix)
}
```

and, to be 100% sure, the multiply-method... we have an object here (is like a static method for all java-devs)

```
def multiply(left: Matrix4, right: Matrix4): Matrix4 =
{
    val matrix: Matrix4 = new Matrix4(left)
    matrix.multiply(right)

    matrix
}
```

there is a copy-constructor in there and the multiply-method of the class-instance is:

```
def multiply(right: Matrix4): Unit =
{
    set(
      this.m00 * right.m00 + this.m10 * right.m01 + this.m20 * right.m02 + this.m30 * right.m03,
      this.m01 * right.m00 + this.m11 * right.m01 + this.m21 * right.m02 + this.m31 * right.m03,
      this.m02 * right.m00 + this.m12 * right.m01 + this.m22 * right.m02 + this.m32 * right.m03,
      this.m03 * right.m00 + this.m13 * right.m01 + this.m23 * right.m02 + this.m33 * right.m03,
      this.m00 * right.m10 + this.m10 * right.m11 + this.m20 * right.m12 + this.m30 * right.m13,
      this.m01 * right.m10 + this.m11 * right.m11 + this.m21 * right.m12 + this.m31 * right.m13,
      this.m02 * right.m10 + this.m12 * right.m11 + this.m22 * right.m12 + this.m32 * right.m13,
      this.m03 * right.m10 + this.m13 * right.m11 + this.m23 * right.m12 + this.m33 * right.m13,
      this.m00 * right.m20 + this.m10 * right.m21 + this.m20 * right.m22 + this.m30 * right.m23,
      this.m01 * right.m20 + this.m11 * right.m21 + this.m21 * right.m22 + this.m31 * right.m23,
      this.m02 * right.m20 + this.m12 * right.m21 + this.m22 * right.m22 + this.m32 * right.m23,
      this.m03 * right.m20 + this.m13 * right.m21 + this.m23 * right.m22 + this.m33 * right.m23,
      this.m00 * right.m30 + this.m10 * right.m31 + this.m20 * right.m32 + this.m30 * right.m33,
      this.m01 * right.m30 + this.m11 * right.m31 + this.m21 * right.m32 + this.m31 * right.m33,
      this.m02 * right.m30 + this.m12 * right.m31 + this.m22 * right.m32 + this.m32 * right.m33,
      this.m03 * right.m30 + this.m13 * right.m31 + this.m23 * right.m32 + this.m33 * right.m33
    )
  }
```

where set(...) just sets the var(iable)s of the Matrix4... so first line is m00, last line is m33.

```
def set(  m00: Float, m01: Float, m02: Float, m03: Float,
          m10: Float, m11: Float, m12: Float, m13: Float,
          m20: Float, m21: Float, m22: Float, m23: Float,
          m30: Float, m31: Float, m32: Float, m33: Float): Unit =
  {
    this.m00 = m00
    this.m01 = m01
    this.m02 = m02
    this.m03 = m03
    this.m10 = m10
    this.m11 = m11
    this.m12 = m12
    this.m13 = m13
    this.m20 = m20
    this.m21 = m21
    this.m22 = m22
    this.m23 = m23
    this.m30 = m30
    this.m31 = m31
    this.m32 = m32
    this.m33 = m33
  }
```

Maybe the multiplication is wrong (could be, but would be really strange to me, as I verified that before)

Comment: Well, _something_ is wrong with at least one of your matrices. It might help if you dump the values of your matrices for some specific arguments (like 90 and 45 degrees). Maybe your shader is wrong, too.

Comment: I feel it weird that your cube is actually changing shape. From no angle should it even be reduced to a vertical line. Feels to me that you are actually modifying your cube and not just the view.

Comment: Looks to me as if scaling would be zero when angle = 90°

Comment: You must be using a projection matrix as well? My money is on the projection matrix being broken. Or, as @derhass already suggested, there's something weird going on in the vertex shader. For example, you could be applying the matrices in the wrong order.

Comment: @derhass Updated the code, added (vertex) shader code, projectionMatrix-generation, viewProjectionMatrix-generation, and modelViewProjectionMatrix-Generation alongside the necessary methods in Matrix4.scala

Comment: val yScale: Float = ((1.0f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio).toFloat You need to drop the *aspectRatio here if I'm not mistaken, but this won't fix your problem, just a bit of stretching maybe.

Comment: I think I found the issue, comparing your Matrix.rotate code with the linked code, you first change the "this.m00 = t00" and then later you do "this.m20 = this.m00 * f20 + this.m10 * f21 + this.m20 * f22", using the modified this.m00. You do this a couple of times. The code you linked does it the other way around, logically your mileage will vary. Simply swap the two/three blocks of code and you'll be fine, it appears. Please report back if this was the problem.

Comment: @HenkDeBoer Make it an answer and I'll accept it. (Thank you very much!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing your `Matrix.rotate` code with the linked code, you first do

`this.m00 = t00`

and then later you do

```
this.m20 = this.m00 * f20 + this.m10 * f21 + this.m20 * f22
```

using the this.m00 you just modified. You do this a couple of times in a similar way. The example code does this the other way around, which means the end result is different. Swap the code blocks and all should be fine. I hope LWJGL will soon decide to add the linear algebra classes back in!

Comment: Yeah, tinkering with it is fun. But there's a difference between doing something mathematical and painstakingly convincing your computer to do something mathematical, this was certainly in the latter category.I feel the matrix classes are there so you can do the math without the boring parts, essentially :)

Comment: The really embarrassing part is, that I missed that I reused a variable I just set while looking through that code like a dozen times. I was so sure that the error was in the rotate-method, yet I didn't find it -.-

Comment: This is a very common thing to happen, which is why sometimes getting some new eyes on your code can fix a problem in 10 secs. Its also why some people advise to never copy paste code. Getting some sleep helps too ^^ One of the best ways to learn debugging is trying to answer questions here, I think.